Juniper Bulk CoA example for accumulation of CoA requests
I am working in BNG implementation with Juniper MX960 and I am interested in Bulk CoA feature to address accumulation of a series of CoA requests and commits all of them together. But I don't find any example of how send the bulk coa message from Radius.
According with the follow link:
https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/subscriber-mgmt-services/topics/topic-map/dynamic-service-activation.html
"Bulk CoA requires each individual request to contain a single instance of the Juniper Networks Bulk-CoA-Transaction-Id VSA (26–194). This VSA identifies requests as belonging to the same bulk transaction; 26–194 must have the same value in all CoA requests in the bulk series. Each successive bulk transaction in the session must have a different identifier; for example, three successive bulk transactions can have IDs of 1, 2, and 1, but cannot have successive IDs of 1, 1, and 2. In practice, the Bulk-CoA-Transaction-Id value typically is incremented for multiple bulk transactions, but this is not required. An ID value used in a given subscriber session can also be used in different subscriber sessions."
Does anyone have an example of how to send this message from the Radius?

I found an example for a simple CoA in Juniper support portal: https://supportportal.juniper.net/s/article/Subscriber-Management-How-to-dynamically-apply-a-service-session-using-RADIUS-CoA but I don't find a example with the bulk CoA

CoA (and bulk CoA) requests will come from the RADIUS server and will depend upon your particular RADIUS software. The Juniper documentation is simply stating that it supports the processing of bulk CoA requests.
